# Announcing a once in a life time badge! (The Beta badge!)

Tags: discussion, badges

In case you missed the announcement: participating in the private beta stage will give you a chance to receive a badge that is only obtainable within a limited time frame. This is called the [Beta badge](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/), and it can be awarded to you after the end of the private beta by completing the following tasks:

> Voted 10 times, added 3 posts score > 0, and visited the site on 3 separate days **during the private beta.**

**Note: these task must be done before the private beta ends.**

As a participant in the private beta, you are helping to initially build this site. Become a pioneer and be remembered forever in the history of PA.SE by earning this badge.

<sub>Inspired  by a similar post from Nike Dattani on Matters Modeling Stack Exchange.</sub>